# SSL: error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, https

To enable https on my node js app I have followed this [page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-nodejs.html)

And included `.ebextensions\https-instance.config` file in my app. I sent my csr to Godaddy and downloaded my cert file.

When running app on local host I create my https server using the keys like below and app runs fine

```
var options = { cert: fs.readFileSync('e03aae55b05ee109.pem'), key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem') };
```

In my **https-instance.config** file I pasted the contents of my key and cert into area specified in the link. I validated the YAML using an [online parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/)

Im getting an 503 service unavailble error when hitting domain and on checking the app logs its throwing out

**[emerg] 21361#0: PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX("/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt") failed (SSL: error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode)**

I have validated my key and cert as described here and they [match](https://ma.ttias.be/openssl-validate-that-certificate-matches-signs-the-private-key/)

Any thoughts on what else could be wrong?

Comment: Is your key and certificate in the PEM format? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-enhanced_Electronic_Mail#Sample_PEM_format_x_509_cert

Comment: indentation was wrong got it fixed thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

indentation was wrong. Needed to be multiline. i had it as single line when trying to fix it in parser

```
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      MIIFSDCCBDCgAwIBAgIJAOA6rlWwXuEJMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIG0MQswCQYD
      VQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UECBMHQXJpem9uYTETMBEGA1UEBxMKU2NvdHRzZGFsZTEa
```

Comment: how do you get your key?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I missed a character from SAML, I've realized it later.

I corrected the cert in my config, and after restart of my app the issue got resolved.